# Creating a rails application with using Google Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an app that reads from a gmail feed. I'm following the instructions listed here for how to get started with google apis on rails.

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html#AuthSub

I followed the instructions exactly (except I also included gem 'gdata' in my gem file) and keep getting the following error when I start the local server.

```
/Users/Kim/Code/Whensitcoming/config/environment.rb:8: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
from /Users/Kim/Code/Whensitcoming/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /Users/Kim/Code/Whensitcoming/config.ru:3
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /Users/Kim/Code/Whensitcoming/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /Users/Kim/Code/Whensitcoming/config.ru:1
```

If I comment out the google related code, the server starts fine. Any tips?

Comment: please provide google related code

Comment: Google code is here: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html#SetupRails

Answer (score 0):

The gdata rails gem looks outdated (February 2009). It most likely won't run under Rails 3. I'm looking for an alternative myself. Until an updated gem arrives, the only way seems to be to use the web service API directly (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/).